# How to use a POD which is compiled in Swift 3.0, into a Project made in 2.2?

Tags: ios, swift, migration, swift3, cocoapods

I made my project in 2.2. Now I want to use a library which is compiled in 3.0. how can I use it.

I tried making legacy to NO and YES, and Unspecified, but not working. If I do Yes, it gives lots of errors as code is in 3.0, and I want 2.2 as base.

NOw what should I do

```
 pod 'EZSwipeController'
```

Its screenshot of document.

[image]

This is library

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is pretty simple: You can't mix Swift 2 and Swift 3 codebases. Either you upgrade your project to Swift 3 (which probably makes sense anyways), or you backport the library you want to use to Swift 2.

Comment: 1. Code is huge, I can't convert urgently, I have deadline
2. Secondly, there is no swift older version than 3.0. 

Now what else is option?

Comment: That you have deadlines doesn't change realities. You have to choose between porting your code, or porting the libraries code, or not using the library, or maybe an older version. ABI compatibility is only planned for Swift 4.

Comment: Looking at EZSwipeController - this looks actually pretty tiny (100 loc?). If it's just that and your own codebase is large, I would probably just port the lib.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, I am using a Swift 2.2 code in my project and i have installed `EZSwipeController` using pods and project is running successfully.

Here is what you needs to be done,

First select your Project

Check the screenshot

[image]

Then in the Build setting for the target set Use Legacy Swift Language Version to yes, like this

[image]

Now from the side navigation select Pods and then select EZSwipeController, like this

[image]

set Use Legacy Swift Language Version to yes.

By making this changes it will work.

Comment: Also, update to CocoaPods 1.1.1 so that changes to swift language in Build Settings of any pods are persisted across 'pod install'.